# Analysis of series using ratio test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

1. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2+1}{n+2}$$
2. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{b (n!)}{n^n}$$ where $b \in \mathbb{N}$.
3. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{10^{n+(-1)^n}}$$ and yes, the entire thing is an exponent.
4. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{5^n}{2^n+1}$$

Given these equations above, which of the following would the ratio test work on? The only fact I know about the ratio test is that if the limit of $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|=1$, then it fails.

For the 1st, I simply applied the ratio test and got 1, so the ratio test is ineffective. For the 2nd, the $b$ actually cancels out, so it's not relevant. It ends up being something like $\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n (n+1)}$, which is not 1.

For the 3rd, I separated the $10^{n+(-1)^n} \implies 10^n  10^{(-1)^n}$ and it ended up being a real number that is $0$? I wasn't sure about this result. The last one was just expanding and simplifying, and I got $\frac{-5}{2}$.

Overall, only the first one fails the ratio test, if I calculated it correctly. Let me know if I did anything wrong

Also, I know that I can use easier tests, like for the 4th, use the alternate series test, but this is how it is.

Comment: The Ratio Test is useless on series which have general terms that are rational functions of polynomials; it works "best" on general terms involving exponential-type functions, factorials, and related functions such as products of factors in arithmetic progression.  For your #1 , you would want something like the Limit Comparison Test (or even the Integral Test), although you can pretty much "eyeball" that it is divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Indeed it fails here, for the reason you gave.
2. Note that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n(n+1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{(1+1/n)^n(n+1)}=0.$$Therefore, the test does not fail in this case.
3. In this case, the quotient is $10^{-3}$ in half the cases and $10$ in the other half. So, the test fails in this case.
4. In other to apply the ratio test in the fourth case, apply it to the absolute values (that is, to the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{5^n}{2^n+1}$). You will get $\frac52$. So, the test works (and it tells you that the series diverges).

Comment: Thank you. very helpful.